# Hauppauge WinTV-dual HD - Dual, Triple Mode, TV Tuner and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tv-tuner

So I have the Hauppauge WinTV-dual HD - Dual, Triple Mode, TV Tuner and successfully installed it under Ubuntu following the hauppage tutorials, installing their PPA etc.

- [Ubuntu support for Hauppauge TV tuners](http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/site/support/linux.html)

However under tvheadend I'm only seeing one tuner.

I've googled a solution and there is talk of patches etc but I have no idea what they mean by this (still a Linux newbie) so was wondering if anyone has this usb dongle and have successfully got both tuners to work and more importantly can give me some steps to get there myself.

Any help at all appreciated.